# Mysql joining sharing data between tables

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join, join

I have a problem with join in mysql, I am trying to populate Name field from bands table in to band_name field in orders table when band_id from orders table matches Band_id from bands table. 
its all confusing and would like some advise or help.

**my code**

```
 <?php
        }   

        $user = new User();
        $user_name = escape($user->data()->username);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT bands.Name FROM bands LEFT JOIN orders ON bands.Band_id = orders.band_id WHERE orders.band_id = 1 AND user_name = '"mysql_real_escape_string($user_name)"'");
       //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_name)."'");


        echo '<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>My bookings</th>
        <th>gig No</th>
        </tr>';

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo 
                "<tr>
                <td>".$row['user_name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['band_id']."</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<tr><td>No bookings</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: Please show the code on how you would "put 122 in band_id in `orders`".

Comment: I would just use a simple insert

Comment: Your user_name column is ambigious. Does it even exist in any of the tables used in this query?

Comment: yes user_name is in the orders table, if the user_name matches the one of the user logged in it shows all transaction from them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM bands
LEFT JOIN orders as user_orders ON(
user_orders.band_id = bands.band_id
AND user_orders.user_name = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($user_name).'"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching your use of the DB slightly wrong.

Your `bands` table should contain all the info you need on a band. Such as this:

```
| id | name        |
====================
| 1  | The Beatles |
| 2  | Blur        |
etc
```

Your `orders` table should contain all or your order data:

```
| id | band_id |
================
| 1  | 2       |
| 2  | 1       |
| 3  | 1       |
```

As you an see, there are 2 orders for The Beatles, and 1 order for Blur.

You could get the band name for an order like so:

```
SELECT bands.name FROM orders, bands, WHERE orders.id = 1 AND orders.band_id = bands.id;
```

Using an inner join:

```
SELECT bands.name FROM bands INNER JOIN orders ON bands.id = orders.band_id WHERE orders.id = 1;
```

Using a left join:

```
SELECT bands.name FROM bands LEFT JOIN orders ON bands.id = orders.band_id WHERE orders.id = 1;
```

UPDATE:

Refer to this image for more details on joins:

[image: SQL join examples]

Taken from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542431/less-number-of-records-for-left-join-vs-inner-join).

Comment: Please fix the join syntax so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: LOL, ok ... I was being lazy and trying to keep things simple

Comment: The left join will only match those records where orders.id is equal to 1. Assuming that's a unique column then only 1 row will be returned. If you're really concerned then add to the where clause that `bands.id IS NOT NULL` but I don't think that's necessary in this case. I'm of the understanding that on the whole, `LEFT JOIN` is more efficient then `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Ah well, both work. He can pick and choose. I've added an inner join to my answer with everything else.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the query im currently using, this is the one i need to modify

Comment: I've added a SQL join diagram from another SO question to help illustrate things. @Beep You shouldn't be storing the band name in 2 places. Don't store the band name in the orders table, just store a foreign key for the band's row in the bands table.